# Horizontal repeat using Flex is not Working

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to get text boxes in ngFor to align horizontally, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

In the HTML of the parent, I have:

```
<div class="maintenance-section">
    <div class="yearly">
        <div *ngFor="let maintenanceCost of editableCostClass.maintenanceCosts; let i = index">
            <maintenance-cost-form [maintenanceCost]="maintenanceCost" [index]="i" [lastModified]="lastModified"
                (maintenanceCostUpdate)="onMaintenanceCostUpdate()"></maintenance-cost-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS of the parent I have:

```
.maintenance-section {
  width: 1250px !important;
}

.yearly {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

In the child component I have:

```
<div class="maintenance-cost">
    <div><label class="required">Year {{index}}</label></div>
    <div><input class="year" type="text" mask="0.000" [(ngModel)]="maintenanceCost"></div>
</div>
```

In the CSS of the child component, I have:

.maintenance-cost{
width: 107px;

```
label {
    justify-self: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.required::after {
    content: '*';
    color: #CC0000;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the issue? If you are trying to get the items aligning side by side in a row, you should use `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: OMG!  Thank you so much!  I was thinking I needed to tell it "columns".  I'm just learning so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
label.required {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).